# problem in showing an img open from zip archive

Tags: php

iam get the img date from the zip archive by getFromIndex()
and the date like that (this the first line of text appearing)

```
‰PNG  ��� IHDR���@���@���ªi
```

know how i can makke appear
iam used

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

but its did not worked
and used

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($data);
imagedestroy($im);
```

but its did not worked and giving me
Warning: imagepng(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource

now you asked me about the date format
we assume the output is

```
$date =  file_get_contents('http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png');
```

the text appear is the same format
but i must use $date because i must get the contents first

Comment: its show me ‰PNG  ��� IHDR���@���@���ªi

Comment: well it should. it is purpose of your script - to output this very data

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this image data is not the only output of this script, right?
But it must be.

Comment: @moustafa so what? can you answer my question? is it the only data your script outputs? can you post here the whole script code?

Answer (score 0):

The data already looks like a PNG file (notice the magic number). What happens if you output the data to a file ? Or How about just echo the data and don't call imagepng. Will that work ?